# Integrating over a Parameter in a FindRoot term

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, replacement

I try to integrate over a parameter `c` in a function using `FindRoot`:

```
f[y_] := FindRoot[x^3 + y^3 + c, {x, 1.}]

f[2] /. c -> 4
```

gives an error:

```
FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {9. +c} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {1.}.
```

but still evaluates correctly:

```
Out= {x -> -2.28943}
```

and with a definition like this:

```
f[y_] := Hold[FindRoot[x^3 + y^3 + c, {x, 1.}]]

f[2] /. c -> 4 // ReleaseHold
```

evaluates cleanly.

The problem lies in `Integrate` providing the parameter `c` as integration variable. (`NIntegrate` as well)

```
Integrate[x /. f[2.], {c, 0, 4}] 

Integrate[x /. (f[2.] // ReleaseHold), {c, 0, 4}]
```

both give an error message:

```
FindRoot::nlnum: The function value {9. +c} is not a list of numbers with dimensions {1} at {x} = {1.}. >>
ReplaceAll::reps: {FindRoot[x^3+2.^3+c,{x,1.}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
...
ReplaceAll::argx: "x/. FindRoot[x^3+2.^3+c,{x,1.}] called with 3 arguments; 1 argument is expected."
```

Is there any way to tell `FindRoot` to wait for the actual value from `Integrate` or to tell `Integrate` to first replace any integration variable with actual numerical values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your function `f` only for numeric values of `c`:

```
f[y_, c_?NumericQ] := x /. FindRoot[x^3 + y^3 + c, {x, 1.}];
NIntegrate[f[2., c], {c, 0, 4}]
```

> -8.60486

Comment: So you just added a?NumericQ to my answer and posted it? :D

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer! But it's also a different idea.. I circumvent the error while you suppress the error message. Can make a huge difference when `f` is very complicated!

Comment: That would have made a good comment. But who cares, I just wanted to help him. I deleted mine.

Comment: @MathX: in the comments of your deleted post, we came to the conclusion that it was more of a problem using Integrate. Using NIntegrate with a //Quiet, one can

Comment: @MathX: in the comments of your deleted post, we came to the conclusion that it was more of a problem using Integrate. Using NIntegrate with a "//Quiet", one can omit the correct, but a little redundant use of the c_ as variable. I tried unsuccessfully something like ##?NumericQ, the idea beeing, like in M.Stern's solution, to tell f to wait till all symbols (parameters) are replaced by numerical values in a general fashion.

Answer (score 3):

For a function like yours that depends on the black box function [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot), you will have to make do with [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate) *(@MStern's answer is the canonical method for this approach)*. There is no way that [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) will be able to symbolically integrate such a function. On the other hand, if you are able to use a symbolic solver instead, then you should be able to make headway with [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate). Your example is one where [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) can be used. Here is the solution using [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve):

```
sol = x /. First @ Solve[x^3 + y^3 + c == 0, x, Reals]
```

> Root[c + y^3 + #1^3 &, 1]

Unfortunately, [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) is not able to integrate such an object:

```
Integrate[sol, c] //TeXForm
```

> $\int \operatorname{Root}\left[\#1^3+c+y^3\&,1\right] \, dc$

However, we can use [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals) to convert to a form that [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) can handle:

```
rad = ToRadicals[sol]
```

> (-1)^(2/3) (-c - y^3)^(1/3)

Let's check the output when $c=4$ and $y=2$:

```
ComplexExpand[rad /. {c->4, y->2}]
%//N
```

> -2^(2/3) 3^(1/3)
>
> -2.28943

This agrees with your expected output. Now, we can use [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate):

```
Integrate[rad /. y->2, {c, 0, 4}]
% //N
```

> 12 - 9 2^(2/3) 3^(1/3)
>
> -8.60486

which agrees with the other answers.